# jQuery Mobile popup doesn't open when loaded via ajax load method

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, popup

my jQuery Mobile popups no longer "pop up" when they are loaded via ajax. I click on the popup but nothing happens.

This is the code I'm using to load the content which includes the popup:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", ".main", function () {
    $('.links').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.container').load(url + '.bin', function () {
            $(".pops").popup();
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

I tried to initialize the popup using  `$( ".pops" ).popup();` but that hasn't made any difference.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

To get *popup* working properly, it should be a direct *child* of *page div*. It will malfunction if placed inside any other div.

The solution is to add a *place holder* div inside *page div*, `.load("url .selector")` <sup>**1**</sup> the popup div specifically, replace it with *place holder* and then initialize it `.popup()`.

**Target page**

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div class=".popup-place-holder">
    <!-- place holder for popup -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Popup**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="pop" data-history="false" data-dismissible="false">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-shadow">Close</a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(".any-button").on("click", function () {
        $(".popup-place-holder").load("URL #pop", function (data) {
            var popup = $(this).find("#pop"); /* find popup inside place-holder */
            $(this).replaceWith(popup); /* replace place-holder with popup div */
            popup.popup(); /* initialize popup */
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2c79dnyw/show/)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2c79dnyw/embedded/js/)**

<sup>**1**</sup> `.selector` is popup div.

Comment: Hi Omar, thank you for your effort and quick response! I found that the popups do work after all - I was using the wrong selector.